# How can I include the ability to take screenshots of my current screen in the same way as Upwork Tracker does?

Tags: angular, html2canvas

In Angular 11, I've attempted to capture a full window screenshot automatically every 10 minutes.To achieve this, I initially implemented the screenshot capture logic triggered by a button click event.However, my goal is to make the screenshot capture time-based rather than event-driven.

I've integrated the html2canvas package to facilitate the screenshot capture process.The issue lies in adapting the code to capture the screenshot automatically at predefined time intervals.

The desired functionality involves scheduling a task to take a screenshot every 10 minutes without user interaction.

It's essential to explore methods like timers or schedulers to achieve this time-based capture.The challenge may revolve around handling asynchronous code execution in Angular.Properly configuring and managing the timing aspect is crucial for this functionality.

I'm seeking guidance or suggestions on how to implement this automated, time-based screenshot capture in Angular 11 using html2canvas

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'html2canvas capture in Angular';

  capturedImage;
  constructor() {}

  clickme() {
    let element = document.querySelector('#capture');
    html2canvas(element as HTMLElement, {
      imageTimeout: 1,
      allowTaint: true,
      useCORS: true,
    }).then((canvas) => {
      this.capturedImage = canvas.toDataURL();
      const imageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.setAttribute('href', imageData);
      link.click();
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ngx-capture` and `setTimer` in the root component will do the trick?

https://github.com/Wanchai/ngx-capture